# Error Aptana Studio, Cannot open it on Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: java, aptana, aptana3

I have a problem with Aptana Studio 3.6.1, It's success installation but when I try to start up the program, it show the message error below.

```
Java was started by returned exit code = 13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Xms128
-Xmx512m
--Xverify:none
-Declipes.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipes.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256
-jar C:\User\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana
Stuido\\plugins\org.eclipes.equinox.laucher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win 32
-ws win32
-showsplash
-laucher C:\Users\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana\Studo\AptanaStudo3.exe
-name aptana Stido 3
--laucher.libray C:\Users\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana 
Studo\\plugins/org.eclipes.equinox.laucher.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclopes_1503.dll
-starup C:\Users\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana
Studio\\plugins/org.eclipes.equinox.laucher_13.0.v20130327-144-.jar
--laucher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata acc_74
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.lgo.size.ax=1000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=ture
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jav C:\Users\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana
Stuido\\plugins/org.eclipese.equionox.laucher_1.3.0.v.20130327-1440.jar
```

Comment: just re-install your java. then launch aptana after.it will work fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the bit version of Aptana Studio that you're using matches the bit version of java you have installed.

If you have 64-bit java installed, then you need to have installed the 64-bit version of Aptana Studio.

Unfortunately you can't use the same Aptana Studio installation to run via both 32-bit and 64-bit Java versions, because the launcher expands a set of 32 or 64-bit specific library features the first time you launch it.

**Edit:**
Based on more detailed reading, you are definitely trying to run a 32-bit version of Aptana:

```
--laucher.libray C:\Users\samphors\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana 
Studo\\plugins/org.eclipes.equinox.laucher.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclopes_1503.dll
```

...this means that you need to have a 32-bit version of java installed; that or install a 64-bit version of Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Install Java for 32Bit on your 64Bit system and it work.